# Nodemailer works well on localhost and server over HTTP, but mail don't received over HTTPS

Tags: email, ssl, nginx, https, nodemailer

Setup a front thank to VueJS with a basic contact form. Backend is a feathers (node/express) API with a POST route to a mail service (nodemailer) that handle to send the email to the account.

On my machine (localhost) everything is working.
Put on my own server (Ubuntu 17.04) over HTTP (served by Nginx) it's working.

I added let's encrypt SSL certificate.

Now the client received a 200 response when I send an email. I have no error on the server (connection check with `transporter.verify()`). But I don't get email anymore.

What do I have to configure with a HTTPS connexion ?

Comment: Sometimes it may not be a problem with config but some cloud providers don't let mails go through, sometimes the IPs are blocked by receiver email server, sometimes the mails go to Junk emails. That is the reason one should use a mail service provider like Amazon SES, SendGrid. So try sending a email manually using the mail command and see if you receive the same in your mailbox or not

Comment: Thank you. Like I wrote, it's working on the server with HTTP. Since I added HTTPS the mail seems to be send from my service but lost or not accepted somewhere.

Comment: Any firewalls on the machine? Which OS? which firewalls are active?

Comment: Nope I didn't setup ufw yet. I'm on Ubuntu 17.04

Comment: Any rows from this `iptables -S| grep -i reject` and `iptables -S | grep -i drop`

Comment: Nothing to show

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154622/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-ragnar).